# ELPA package disappears from list after deletion

Tags: emacs, package, init

I am new to emacs. After installing a package in emacs, I clicked the `delete` button to remove it. Now I would like to reinstall it. However, it does not show up anywhere on the *Packages* list. I have deleted my `.emacs` file. I have deleted `.emacs.d/` I have even uninstalled emacs. And yet that cursed package will not show up in the list. What environment variables are causing this package to be banished forever from my computer????

Answer (score 0):

So the secret sauce was:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
```

This caused the deleted package to reappear.

Comment: You can also type `r` in the `*Packages*` buffer.